# Explode() function to break up string into 2 subsequent arrays php

Tags: php, string-formatting

I'm trying to split the $param variable below in the format

```
listofitems//listofitems//listofitems...
```

where each item is in the format

```
event,event,event,event...
```

into individual events (numbers) which are passed to my checkuseritems function. At the moment I'm only getting the first listofitems (1,4,9,7,5,8) and then 149758 with the echo functions. Why are the other two lists being ignored?

```
   $param= "1,4,9,7,5,8//5,8,9,6,4,2//8";
   $item = explode("//",$param);
   $allitemslength = count($item);
   $alluseritems["list"] = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < $allitemslength; $x++) {
    echo($item[$x]);


   $id = explode(",",$item[$x]);
   $arrlength = count($id);



    $response["item"] = array();


   for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

 echo ($id[$x]);

  //  $result= $db->checkuseritems($id[$x]);
}
}
```

Comment: maybe because you use `$x` for both for loops! So use 2 variables for 2 for loops.

Comment: isn't the scope of x limited to that loop

Comment: No it is not. Try it and change `$x` to `$y` in your seconds loop and you will see your code working